# Resolving  in-call audio issue on my Android phone programatically?

Tags: android, audio

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note and has an in-call audio problem.

When I place a call or receive a call, no audio is heard from the earpiece, speakers, headset or Bluetooth headset from both sides of the call.

However, when I play music or videos, record audio and video, make voice calls on skype and ym, no problems are experienced with the earpiece, speaker, Bluetooth headset or headset.

How can I resolve this issue?
Has anyone experienced a similar issue where they can possibly aid me with a fix of a link to a guide on how to resolve this?

I've tried:

- upgrading to ics 4.0.3
- flashing other stock roms
- flashing stock kernels
- doing full wipes

None of these actions resolved my issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site explicitly for programming questions. You're better off asking your question at another site – [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) might be the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Try this app with the Pro Key.  The Pro key enables settings for phone call sound routing.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix